# TextField center in container in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i need to do textfield in center in container.
what i want to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgbbx.png)

My text field don't get centered.

```
Container(
      child: Center(
             child: TextField(
               controller: _coins,
                          ),
                       ),
                   ),
```

what should i change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

TextField will be fit to the container size. You can see the TextField in the center when you provide width and height for it.

Please try the below codes:

```
Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 150.0,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```